# Performance of a shared Angular Material module that may include many Component modules?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

The [Angular Material component usage guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) suggests creating a shared module to include multiple components. My question here is about shared module usage.

### Shared Angular Material Module

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule],
  exports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule],
})
export class MyOwnCustomMaterialModule { }
```

This shared module could contain many component modules. Maybe 50 or more. Let's say I have imported this shared module into another module where it needs only one material module. In such cases, is there a performance penalty, for example, for loading time? Are shared modules cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**NgModule FAQs**](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#ngmodule-faqs) include the following notes.

> ## [What if I import the same module twice?](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice)
>
> That's not a problem. ***When three modules all import Module 'A', Angular evaluates Module 'A' once, the first time it encounters it, and doesn't do so again.***
>
> That's true at whatever level A appears in a hierarchy of imported NgModules. When Module 'B' imports Module 'A', Module 'C' imports 'B', and Module 'D' imports [C, B, A], then 'D' triggers the evaluation of 'C', which triggers the evaluation of 'B', which evaluates 'A'. When Angular gets to the 'B' and 'A' in 'D', ***they're already cached and ready to go***.
>
> Angular doesn't like NgModules with circular references, so don't let Module 'A' import Module 'B', which imports Module 'A'.

---

There is an additional performance benefit by only including the Angular Material component modules needed for a specific application.

The [**deprecation notice for Angular Material beta.3**](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#materialmodule) states:

> ## MaterialModule
>
> `MaterialModule` (and `MaterialRootModule`) have been marked as deprecated.
>   We've found that, with the current state of tree-shaking in the world, that using an aggregate `NgModule` like `MaterialModule` leads to tools not being able to eliminate code for components that aren't used.
>
> In order to ensure that users end up with the smallest code size possible, we're deprecating `MaterialModule`, to be removed in the a subsequent release.
>
> To replace `MaterialModule`, users can create their own "Material" module within their application (e.g., `GmailMaterialModule`) that imports only the set of components actually used in the application.

This same advice still applies as of 2019. The [Angular Material getting started guide states](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules):

> Alternatively, you can create a separate `NgModule` that imports and then re-exports all of the *Angular Material components that you will use in your application*. By exporting them again, other modules can simply include your `CustomMaterialModule` wherever Material components are needed, and automatically get all of the exported Material modules. A good place for importing/exporting the application-wide Material modules is the `SharedModule`.

Comment: You're referring 2017 release note. But I have put the latest doc of material guidance. So then? https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: @Sampath The current Angular Material getting started guide still recommends limiting the Component modules to those needed by your app to improve performance. See note from the NgModule FAQ about modules being cached.

Answer (score 3):

**Stop Using Shared Material Module**

I'd thought as same as the people who answered this question before testing the performance of the way that the majority of Angular articles recommend it, but like this [article](https://indepth.dev/stop-using-shared-material-module), I came into the below conclusion:

> Stop Using Shared Material Module

As can be seen in the article, it's not good idea to incorporate all Angular modules in a  module. The testing the result is simple as ABC.

The another significant point is that the link mentioned in other answers. For example, this [Getting Started with Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules), there isn't any recommend to create a module for exporting Angular Material modules right now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question a while back and I found and bookmarked this article: [Avoiding Common Confusions with Modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f#482d), written by [Max Koretskyi aka Wizard](https://blog.angularindepth.com/@maxim.koretskyi)

> ### Module Caching
>
> Once in a while a new question pops up on stackoverflow from a developer worried that **importing a module to both lazy and non-lazy module will result in duplication of a module code in runtime**. That’s a understandable assumption. But no need to worry as **all existing module loaders cache the module they load**.
>
> When SystemJS loads a module it puts it in the cache. Next time there’s a request for this module it returns it from cache and doesn’t perform an additional network request. This is the process that happens for every module.
>
> For example, when you write Angular components you import Component decorator from angular/core module:
>
> `import { Component } from '@angular/core';`
>
> **You reference the package lots of times in the application. But SystemJS doesn’t load angular/core package every time. It loads it once and caches it.**
> Something similar happens with Webpack if you use angular-cli or configure the webpack yourself. It includes the module code only once in a bundle and gives it the ID. All other modules import symbols from this module using this ID.

I'd suggest that you give the entire article a read and make some personal notes because it really helped me to clear some doubt about angular's architecture. I think it's really well-written and clearly explained by itself so I am not going to reinvent the wheel and paraphrase it.

---

Anyway, A SharedModule is used to share components, pipes and directives. Although you might be importing 3rd party libraries modules and exporting them to share them. Essentially, you are sharing the components, pipes and directives that are declared in the 3rd party lib's module (in this case, Angular Material's modules).

[SharedModule is compiled into `main-abcd1234.js`](https://itnext.io/how-to-optimize-angular-applications-99bfab0f0b7c), something like in the middle of this post compilation log :

[image]

main-abcd1234.js is loaded at app start. You can verify this by viewing your network tab in your app's initial load.

As you may see, for my current project, it is not really huge, only a few hundreds kilobytes in size. You can test if your "app size" will increase, by importing the shared module into say, a module X, that only uses only 1 component in the shared module and check if the module X's compiled bundle size will increase or not. It wouldn't.

oh, if you're wondering how my chunks are named, you can set `namedChunks` in `angular.json` to true, and run `ng serve --prod`, so you wouldn't see gibberish encoded characters.

Cheers!